# java multithreading program 4

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been asked a question from one of my interview quiz 
the question follows:
A task uses a master thread (not shown here) to share the work of scanning DNA among multiple threads. 
     * The master thread invokes the scanDNA method (below) on all of the other threads at once, with each
     * thread provided with its own private share of the work (the dnaList, individual to each thread).
     * 
     * Each thread shares the common 'results' object as a way to report the progress of the scan to the master
     * thread of the task.  It is very important for the task that the total count of the successful scans is 
     * always accurate.
     * 
     * Improve the overall performance of the task by modifying the scanDNA method below and fix any defects.
     */

```
private interface DNA {
    public boolean scan();
}

public void scanDNA(List<DNA> dnaList, Properties results) {

    synchronized (results) {
        Iterator<DNA> i = dnaList.iterator();

        Object lock = new Object();
        while (i.hasNext()) {

            if (i.next().scan()) {
                String key = "Successful Scans Performed";
                synchronized (lock) {
                    results.setProperty(key, 
                            String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(results.getProperty(key)) + 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot understand this problem I would really thank for solving this out

Comment: how the total count of the scan wil be accurate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By synchronizing via the `results` object at the very beginning of the work the threads thave to wait for each other, this is they will do their work synchron instead of parallel.
Since the input data for each thread is unique to the thread they should calculate the result first (without the synchroniyation) and if the result is available use the syncronization around the `results` and update it. So the lock becomes as short as possible.
The `lock` object itself seems to be useless since every thread creates its own variable for the look.